# Implementing word2vec in python3 WITHOUT gensim

Tags: python-3.x, word2vec

We're running into a lot of problems installing word2vec within python3. We just keep getting a standard error that python can't find the package it's looking for.

> Competition-Repo/agents$ python3
>
> Python 3.4.3  [GCC 4.8.4] on linux
>
> > > > import word2vec
> > > >
> > > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > >         File "", line 1, in  ImportError: No module named 'word2vec'

Most everything I've found has either someone else's implementation of word2vec within python3, or is accessed through Gensim. The pip-install for python2 imports flawlessly, now we need to set up the same thing for python3.

Thanks!
-Ben

Answer (score 0):

I just installed the product from [Github site](https://github.com/cnDelbert/word2vec-py) without incident on Python 3.4 **but Win7Pro**. It imports but who knows after that, right?

It comes with a setup.py. Being an inveterate experimenter I tried that, contrary to instructions. It failed.

At least this is easy to try, assuming you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

How exactly are you importing in python2?

With gensim, you can either import with -

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
```

or with -

```
from gensim.models import word2vec
```

The former is for the class `Word2Vec` and the latter for the module.

There is a tutorial [here](http://rare-technologies.com/word2vec-tutorial/) for getting started

Answer (score 0):

The way we were able to install it was through:

sudo pip3 install cython
sudo pip3 install word2vec

Turned out to be a lot easier than I had thought..